# Is this picture of Beyoncé Knowles real?

Tags: celebrities

I've seen this picture now a few times, is it legit? It's supposed to be [Beyoncé Knowles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonc%E9_Knowles).

[image: Alleged picture of Beyoncé Knowles]

Here is [a claim that assumes it is legit.](http://solsticevisuals.com/post/42487903272/this-is-why-your-photographer-never-sends-all-the)

Comment: I don't understand what there is to be skeptical of? Haven't you ever seen an unflattering picture of someone while they were dancing or doing any other activity?

Comment: @SamIAm meet photoshop. Photoshop meet Sam I Am.

Comment: Yes, I understand photoshop exists, but with many many cameras taking many many pictures of someone **dancing**, I'd be very surprised if there wasn't a few unflattering ones.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely **yes** as the outfit and background are consistent with her appearance at the [Super Bowl XLVII half time show](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/music/posts/la-et-ms-beyonce-superbowl-20130204,0,947429.story). A minor caveat due to the fact that I can't find an official source of the image although [Huffington Post UK is using it](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/02/07/bad-day-at-the-office-for_n_2639183.html?just_reloaded=1).

Similar pictures have actually been turning up due to their [unflattering nature](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lyapalater/the-fiercest-moments-from-beyonces-halftime-show) and this has allegedly led to [Beyoncé’s publicist allegedly wanting some unflattering pictures removed from the internet](http://gawker.com/5981957/beyonces-publicist-wants-to-erase-these-six-unflattering-photos-from-the-internet) which has caused them to [spread](http://now.msn.com/beyonce-pr-team-asks-websites-to-remove-unflattering-pictures) a bit [more](http://news.msn.com/rumors/rumor-beyonc%C3%A9s-publicist-wants-unflattering-super-bowl-photos-gone).

I have found the picture in question with the background removed provided for [stock for a Photoshop Contest](http://deadspin.com/5982561/photoshop-contest-unflattering-beyonce-pictures), as shown below. This to me also backs up it being an original as opposed to manipulated already.

[image]

Comment: [Did I win?](http://i.imgur.com/vMyLIcq.png)